# Происходит ли в Java утечка памяти при циклических ссылках?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора, циклические-зависимости

Сможет ли сборщик мусора в java 11 очистить объекты, имеющие ссылку друг на друга?

```
public class A {
  B b;
  public A(B b){this.b = b;}
}

public class B{
  A a = new A(this);
}

main(){
 var b = new B();
 ...
 b = null;
}
```

Comment: Да, сможет. Значение имеют только _корни_.

Comment: если бы этого не было в алгоритме garbage collector, то и в java 1.0 память бы утекла вся =]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/994962/188366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An object enters an “unreachable” state when no more strong references to it exist. When an object is unreachable then it is a state for collection.

В грубом переводе это означает, что как только объект становится недоступным то попадает в зону "интереса" сборщика мусора. В приложении к циклическим ссылкам это означает, что как только хотя бы 1 из обозначенных объектов не будет иметь внешней ссылки на корневые объекты, то попадет к сборщику мусора. Это хорошо иллюстрируется таким рисунком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"висящие" (недоступные) объекты будут утилизированы сборщиком мусора (даже если они ссылаются друг на друга)